# Getting Records from A DataFrame, one by one

Tags: python, pandas

I'm implementing an API in order to get a data from a database and return the data according to some conditions.

I managed to create a dataframe by using Pandas. Now, my task is to implement a function that returns the records of the dataframe, one by one, like an iterator. Meaning, each time the user calls this method `getRecord(self)`, he gets the next record.

I'm having trouble with implementing this method and I'd really like to get some help. I looked for a ways to do it by using function of Pandas and couldn't find a thing. I also thought about implement the function `__iter__` and `__next__` in my class but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you looked at [`DataFrame.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) ?

Comment: Hey @JonClements, yes, I did. This function returns all the rows together. What I want is to get them one by one each time I call the function, not get them all together. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't though... your class can have it's own iter/next dunder methods/ `getRecords` to yield from the `.iterrows()` call...

Comment: when you say "each time the user calls this method `getRecord(self)`" how does the user call the method? If each call of the user means the script/program runs completely and closes than `.iterrows()` doesn't work because it will reset with the next call. In this case you have to write the last printed row (or id) somewhere persistent and each call should read first the saved row/id and return the next one.

Comment: @Eli What are you trying to do? `iterrows` returns the very iterator you want. You don't need Pandas to iterate query results though. Pandas itself reads data from databases using an ORM, SQLAlchemy, which returns iterable rows. That ORM is already a higher-level abstraction than what you described. Pandas is a client application to the ORM

Comment: First of all, thank you all for your help!  Now, @PanagiotisKanavos - I'm not familiar with ORM or SQLAlchemy.. I used psycopg2 in order to get my database and I used 
Pandas in order to get a dataframe out of it. How can I use ORM or SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @99_m4n - How can I save this id as you suggest? when I say "each time the user calls this method getRecord(self)" I mean that a user can import my python API file into his program and use my methods. among them this method, in order to get a row of the dataframe at a time.

Comment: @Eli Post your code then. The usual way of loading database data into a dataframe is using [pandas.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) which in turn uses SQLAlchemy. If you load the data with psycopg2 why is Pandas involved? In any case, `iterrows` already returns an actual iterator. What you ask is definitely *not* an iterator.

Comment: @Eli - It strongly depends on what you want for your. If your user calls the method multiple times within his/her script something like JAbr's answer should work (as lon as it is with the same object/class. If you want that the "last row" persist even after the user closes his script, you can write a temp file locally with an ID that later you'll read and recognize the last row printed. If you want that all users always get a new row globaly you can write a temp file or save a variable on memory in your server. As I said, it all depends on what you want and what resources do you have.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - My code is too long to post, I can try to explain it and post the relevant parts. First, I'm using 'psycopg2.connect' in order to connect to my database. Then I create a 'self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()'. Next, I create a SQL query in order to get the data I want from the databse and execute by 'cursor.execute(query)'. Now, I want to get the data as dataframe, so I use 'pd.DataFrame(exec_consts_res)'. Finally, inside  'def nextDF(self):', I want to write a code which allows the user who import my file, to get the rows from the dataframe one by one, one row each call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wondering if you are looking something like this -

```
class DfIter:

def __init__(self):
    self.df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4,5], "b": [2,4,8,9,5], "c": [3,4,5,6,7]})
    self.state = 0

def getRecord(self):
    
    while self.state < self.df.shape[0]:
        _data = self.df.iloc[self.state] 
        self.state += 1
        return _data
        
    else: 
        raise IndexError("No more datapoints to return")
```

iter_obj = DfIter()

iter_obj.getRecord()

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you are looking for something as follows -

```
class LazyPandas:

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self.max = df.shape[0]

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n <= self.max:
            result = self.df.iloc[self.n] 
            self.n += 1
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration        

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self


  
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

lazy_df = LazyPandas(df)
i = iter(lazy_df)
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
```

Comment: `iterrows()` already provides an iterator over the rows

Comment: That's a valid point, thought it would be nice to show usage of `__next__` and `__iter__`